# Numbers = 1-5, List = [1,3,4]. How to get back a list [2,5]?

Tags: ruby

I think that the question title explains itself :) Suppose that i have the the numbers 1,2,3,4 and 5.
Now, i have a list [1,3,4].

What is the best way to get back the inverted list ? A list like [2,5] with the missing elements ?

Comment: You shouldn't use the word 'numbers'. If you mean range `1..5`, then you should say so. If you mean an array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, then you should say so. And you also shouldn't use the word 'invert'. It means something totally different from what you have in mind. It's also better to say 'array' instead of 'list' when you are talking about ruby.

Comment: Thanx, but i think people understand what i mean. I'm not writing a literature book, i'm just asking something :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As simple as

```
> [1,2,3,4,5] - [1,3,4]
=> [2, 5]
```

Documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Array.html#M000351).

Comment: That surprised me ! I seriously did not know you could do that. I was about to traverse :O Thanx !

Answer (score 7):

Use the splat operator to create an array from your range of numbers and then subtract out the set

```
> [*1..5]-[1,3,4]
 => [2, 5]
```